# PHP access cifs share

Tags: php, network-share

I need to move files through windows shares by php pages.

In a linux context I will use samba client to mount the share to a local path, however i can not understand how to do this in a windows webserver.

The webserver is running as "SYSTEM" user and I can not specify a valid share user.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, just use the following synthax in the php command "copy":

```
copy("\\server_source\path", "\\server_dest\path");
```

You need permissions to copy files (check the configuration of the webserver you're using, the user who's running the webserver must be included with r/w permissions).

If you haven't permissions, run a

```
system("net use drive1: \\server_source\path password /USER:user@domain.tld");
system("net use drive2: \\server_dest\path password /USER:user@domain.tld");
```

then:

```
copy("drive1:\path", "drive2:\path");
```

You must know which drive letter from Z: down to E: are available on your server.

Comment: Is "net use" global for all account and also for webserver?

Comment: This don't work, I can access drive1:\\ and driver2:\\ but copy fails.

Comment: Which version of Windows you're using?

Comment: Windows Server2012

Comment: Can you post the exact error?

Comment: Warning: copy(Z:\TEST_1.MPF): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\www\test.php on line 3
The code is: copy("Z:\\TEST_1.MPF","c:\\test.txt");
I tried in a cmd: copy Z:\TEST_1.MPF c:\test.txt and this works!

I think this is because SYSTEM user of apache service can not access shares...

Comment: From [http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html):  "By default, all Apache services are registered to run as the system user (the LocalSystem account). The LocalSystem account has no privileges to your network via any Windows-secured mechanism, including the file system, named pipes, DCOM, or secure RPC. It has, however, wide privileges locally."  So, go to that page and follow instructions on how to run apache as a network-enabled account.

Comment: I followed this instrunctions, I made a new user with log as service privileges and now apache is running as that account... however copy still doesn't work.